# Migrating connected apps from one dev org to another dev org with the consumer credentials remain unchanged

Tags: metadata-api, connected-apps

I have been looking for a solution to migrate my connected apps from one dev org to the other since the other one has partner privilege

Is it possible by MetaData API?

Comment: And when I tried to fetch the ConnectedApp metadata components from my dev org with Force.com IDE, it's not pulling my connected apps.so I could not deploy it to the target org

Answer (score 1):

As per [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/70284/how-can-i-deploy-a-connected-app-from-my-sandbox-environment-to-my-production-en), You don't need to package or deploy your connected app. It will be installed automatically and your credential would be same.

> One organization acts as the "host" of the connected app. All other
>   orgs will automatically "install" it on the first use in that org.
>   There's no need to package it up or deploy it anywhere. If you were to
>   create it in every other org, you'd have unique client ID and client
>   secret values, which would be disastrous at best. I would say you
>   should create your Connected App in a permanent org (production or a
>   DE org), rather than a Sandbox, which could be destroyed,
>   coincidentally deleting the Connected App.

Comment: I do accept that ConnectedApp in one dev org will act as a host. As I mentioned, my target dev org has partner privilege and I want to access the REST resources of salesforce professional/group edition in which REST API access is disabled by default. So I want to migrate my connected app to the target dev and make use of "Whitelisting Connected Apps" feature ( as mentioned https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=API-Access-Change-for-Connected-Apps&language=en_US) which will be available for only partner accounts to access the REST resources of salesforce PE/GE.