# Can I connect to a sandbox using JWT Flow and Prod connect app?

Tags: connected-apps, salesforcedx, sandbox-refresh, salesforcedx-cli, jwt

I'm trying to connect to a sandbox using the sfdx cli and the JWT flow through force:auth:jwt:grant. According to [this Salesforce DX doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_auth_jwt_flow.htm), we can use the same connected app information from Production to connect to our Scratch Org.

Is it something that should work for sandbox too ? I'm getting a "Failed: Not approved" error.

Connected app in sandbox comes from the refresh but has a different consumer key. The Permission set is set correctly on my user.

Is there a way to connect to a recently refreshed sandbox using the JWT flow (without manually changing something like the consumer key) ?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the Connected App from your production org, but to avoid the `user hasn't approved this consumer` error, I've found that you need to authenticate using the password and the Connected App's Client Id first.  Then you'll be able to authenticate with JWT using the key.

Comment: Are you using the Production Connected App's Client Id? What command are you using to authenticate?

Comment: Yes, the client id of the Connected App created in prod.  Using force cli, I use `force login -i test --connected-app-client-id xxx`, then `force login -i test --connected-app-client-id xxx -u user@example.com -key path/to/app.key`

Comment: I see, this is possible using https://github.com/ForceCLI/force but its an interactive (browser) session. The first command anyway redirects to an error page. The second, as expected, has the usual `ERROR: user hasn't approved this consumer`

Comment: You'll need to add http://localhost:3835/oauth/callback to your Connected App as a callback url for the interactive authentication.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you are trying to JWT into a developer sandbox just refreshed or created from production. If so, I had the *same exact* problem. I was trying to login with the same --clientid and --jwtkeyfile as the Production org and the --username --instanceurl flags pointing to the sandbox admin user and https://test.salesforce.com respectively. This was failing with:

```
Reason: invalid_grant - user hasn't approved this consumer
```

I was, however, able to login if I used the new/different consumer key from the sandbox.

Not sure this is going to work for my use case, as I'm trying to use developer sandboxes in a CI setup. Not sure how I'll get at those updated consumer key on the freshly created/refreshed developer sandboxes.

Would still be interested to head if any others have a suggestion.

Edit: After digging around a bit, it appears this is a limitation on Salesforce.

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DiZoAAK

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. We have just refresh our sandboxes and GitHub can no longer login "user hasn't approved this consumer".

I have updated the consumer key to point to the new sandbox. All other details are exactly the same.

Any idea how to approve the consumer?