# Access a refreshed sandbox with JWT flow

Tags: authentication

We have a sandbox with a Connected App configured to use the JWT flow for machine-to-machine authentication in a CI/CD setup. We would like to run a nightly refresh from production, but this broke the JWT flow: although the key associated to the connected app we use to sign the JWT is not changed during sandbox refresh, the consumer id is changed every time we refresh the sandbox. Looks like it is expected as per this [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/212573/can-i-connect-to-a-sandbox-using-jwt-flow-and-prod-connect-app)

Can anyone please advise how can we get access to the sandbox after we have refreshed it, in CI/CD? If we have access to production, is there a way we can use it to get login access to sandbox? Or there are other automated ways?

Also, came across this [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/212573/can-i-connect-to-a-sandbox-using-jwt-flow-and-prod-connect-app) but it talks about using new consumer key and not automation. Thanks for the inputs

Comment: From my experience, what you're asking for is impossible (at best, it'd require a fragile chain of hacks). Is there a particular reason why you're not using scratch orgs for this?

Comment: Answer by @xn in the link referenced above has the right idea. You'll have to flesh it out.

Comment: Can you help to flesh it out? What is the tool used to authenticate with production Connected app's client id and password? sfdx doesn't seem to support this flow.