# How to freeze client id at sandbox refresh

Tags: oauth2, connected-apps, sandbox-refresh, client-id

Hy,

I created a new connected app in production.

This connected app has been replicated on my test sandbox when I refreshed It from production.

So, I have a new client id for Security reasons I think. But when I refreshed this sandbox again from production a different client id is created again. It's a problem beacause I need to change this value on all consumers of the test sandbox, it's complex and eavy.

How can I freeze this client id for a particular sanbox ? it's possible to do it programmaticly with a job after refresh ?

Comment: You can't freeze it. A better approach is to use the production connected app for access to sandbox: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/212573/can-i-connect-to-a-sandbox-using-jwt-flow-and-prod-connect-app

Comment: Thanks @identigral for your anwser. If I understand I need to create a new connected app like a proxy that redirect to my sandbox. It's right ? if it is I don't understant how to do this with the link you shared.

Comment: Is it possible to set an other client Id after refresh a sabdbox ?

Comment: No. You either use a newly generated client id or use the production connected app

Comment: have you a documentation about this ?

Comment: @identigral I don't understand how to use a production connected app to work on a sandbox. Can you explain me it ?